# Debugging EXC_BAD_ACCESS in AppKit

Tags: objective-c, debugging, exc-bad-access

I am receiving a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when calling `setFrame` on `NSWindow`. Unfortunately the exception occurs in AppKit where I can't debug it, in `[NSWindow _setFrameCommon:display:stashSize:]` with an invalid address of `0x40dedeadbec0` (the same every time).

The call in my code that causes the exception is in a subclass of `NSWindow`:

```
[super setFrame:frameRect display:flag];
```

Both `frameRect` and `display` are valid values, and `self` is a valid instance of my `NSWindow` subclass.

How should I go about debugging this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need start debuging with enabling NSZombieEnabled. Fast of all NSWindow was released somewhere by some reasons. For example you have releaseWhenClose flag with YES value.
Error address which you provided seems like a [Hexspeak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak)

Comment: Already tried using zombies and it doesn't help; `releaseWhenClose` is set to `NO`. And it's not the window that has been released as when I print out the value of `self` on the above line it is still a valid `NSWindow` object.